# KendoUI: Render template with external variable

Tags: templates, variables, kendo-ui

I'm loading up some stuff via AJAX, and rendering it through kendo, but want to add something to it that's not in the AJAX-loaded data but set as a var in js, something like this:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div style="background-image: url('#= commonBackground #');">
        <h2>#= title #</h2>
    </div>
</script>
```

And then call this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var commonBackground = '/images/background.png';
    var someData = {
        title: 'Lorem Ipsum'
    };
    var someTemplate = kendo.template($('some-template').html());

    $('#target').append(someTemplate(someData));
});
```

Now I know this is horrible code, but I hope I'm getting the point across of what I'm trying to do here. I'm unsure how I should reference `commonBackground` from my template, any help with this? Documentation didn't make me any wiser...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `commonBackground` needs to be global.

Either define it as:

```
var commonBackground = '/images/background.png';
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

or:

```
var commonBackground = undefined;
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $('button').on('click', function(e){
        ...
        commonBackground = '/images/background.png';
        ...
    });
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: Why is not `commonBackground` defined inside the template data as `title` is? I think that it is easier / cleaner doing:

```
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var someData = {
        title           : 'Lorem Ipsum',
        commonBackground: 'background.png'
    };
    var someTemplate = kendo.template($('#some-template').html());
    $('#target').append(someTemplate(someData));
});
```

Comment: It's not in data because I'm reading data from json and I don't have full control over that, so I can't just add a title field to my json-feed, sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: But you extend the `someData` with the extra information just before invoking `$('#target').append(someTemplate(someData))`, don't you?